# Parse JSON with JSONDecoder in Swift 5 using structs

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, jsondecoder

I get from a Rest API a result in json format. Now I wanna parse this JSON with the JSONDecoder but I don't really understand the structure of my response.

For that I already tried to create structs to get the "name" of "FirstUser".

```
{  
   "User":[  
      {  
         "FirstUser":{  
            "name":"John"
         },
         "Information":"XY",
         "SecondUser":{  
            "name":"Tom"
         }
```

Comment: This https://app.quicktype.io/ will help you to parse any JSON and let you know how to make your struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Json**

```
{
    "User":[
      {
        "FirstUser":{
        "name":"John"
        },
       "Information":"XY",
        "SecondUser":{
        "name":"Tom"
      }
     }
   ]
}
```

**Model**

```
// MARK: - Empty
struct Root: Codable {
    let user: [User]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user = "User"
    }
}

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
    let firstUser: FirstUserClass
    let information: String
    let secondUser: FirstUserClass

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstUser = "FirstUser"
        case information = "Information"
        case secondUser = "SecondUser"
    }
}

// MARK: - FirstUserClass
struct FirstUserClass: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

**Parse**

```
do {
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data) 
    print(res.first?.firstUser.name)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works. Can you please explain me what you exactly have done. I wanna understand it.

Answer (score -1):

If I create model using previous json
Using this link [blog]:  http://www.jsoncafe.com to generate Codable structure or Any Format

**Model**

```
import Foundation
struct RootClass : Codable {
    let user : [Users]?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user = "User"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        user = try? values?.decodeIfPresent([Users].self, forKey: .user)
    }
}

struct Users : Codable {
    let firstUser : FirstUser?
    let information : String?
    let secondUser : SecondUser?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstUser = "FirstUser"
        case information = "Information"
        case secondUser = "SecondUser"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        firstUser = try? FirstUser(from: decoder)
        information = try? values?.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .information)
        secondUser = try? SecondUser(from: decoder)
    }
}
struct SecondUser : Codable {
    let name : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try? values?.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
struct FirstUser : Codable {
    let name : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try? values?.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

**Parse**

```
    do {
        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootClass.self, from: data)
        print(res?.user?.first?.firstUser?.name ?? "Yours optional value")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: All those `try?` statements and the catch block in the `Parse` part make no sense. An optional plus `decodeIfPresent` plus `try?` is twice redundant. And also the suggested code generator creates pretty bad code.